# How to set a CEF window icon (in python)

Tags: python, chromium-embedded, cefpython

Not wx, gtk3, pyqt etc... 
I need something like:

cef.Initialize(settings=settings)
window_info = cef.WindowInfo()
browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url="localhost:8080/", window_title="Hello World!" ***icon="myicon.png"***)

Comment: What OS? You can make a native OS call using e.g. ctypes.

Comment: Windows, Linux . Can you show me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux execute `xseticon` program programmtically using `os.system()` function or similar, see: http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/ .

On Windows use ctypes built-in Python module to execute native win32 functions. Example code below. The `_hWnd` variable holds window handle which can be obtained by calling `browser.GetWindowHandle()`.

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from os import path
import platform

LRESULT = c_int64 if platform.architecture()[0] == "64bit" else c_long

SendMessage = windll.user32.SendMessageW
SendMessage.restype = LRESULT
SendMessage.argtypes = [HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM]

GetModuleHandle = windll.kernel32.GetModuleHandleW
GetModuleHandle.restype = HMODULE
GetModuleHandle.argtypes = [LPCWSTR]

IMAGE_ICON = 1
LR_LOADFROMFILE = 0x00000010
LR_CREATEDIBSECTION = 0x00002000

LoadImage = windll.user32.LoadImageW
LoadImage.restype = HANDLE
LoadImage.argtypes = [HINSTANCE, LPCWSTR, UINT, c_int, c_int, UINT]

RelPath = lambda file : path.join(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), file)


def AlterIcon(_hWnd, lpszIcon):

    WM_SETICON = 0x0080
    ICON_BIG = 1

    hModel = GetModuleHandle(None)
    hIcon = LoadImage(hModel,
                      RelPath(lpszIcon),
                      IMAGE_ICON,
                      0, 0,
                      LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION)


    SendMessage(_hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, hIcon)
```

Ref: http://qaru.site/questions/7837596/how-to-include-image-in-message-box-using-ctypes-in-python